# How to find the height ($z$) on an elliptic cone at a point $(x, y)$

Tags: conic-sections

I am attempting to write a java method which returns the height of an elliptic cone given a $(x, y)$ point within the base.

I have an elliptic cone centred at $(x_1, y_1)$, the major axis a, minor axis b and the height of the centre point h.

Given a point $(x_2, y_2)$ [assuming that the point is within the ellipse] how do I find the height of the cone's surface at $(x_2, y_2)$?

Thanks for your help

Jon

Comment: "Given a point $(x_2,y_2)$ [assuming that the point is within the ellipse] how do I find the height of the cone's surface at $(x_2,y_2)$" - if $(x_2,y_2)$ is on the con'e surface, then "the point is within the ellipse", but is instead on its boundary.

Comment: @Sanath I meant that x2, y2 are not on the cone's surface, they are on the x, y plane which the base of the cone lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to post diagrams so will have to ask you to draw your own.

Not quite sure if you said this but I am assuming the vertex of the cone is directly above the centre of the ellipse - if it's off-centre the problem will be rather more difficult.

Draw a cross section through the vertex and the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.  You will see a triangle with two verticals - the larger one the height $h$ of the cone, the smaller one the height say $H$ that you want to calculate.  Call the base of the triangle $r$ and the distance between the verticals $R$.

Hope this doesn't sound too complicated but as I said I don't know how to post diagrams.

By similar triangles,
$$\frac{H}{r-R}=\frac{h}{r}\ .$$
Now we need to find $r$ and $R$.  Draw another diagram showing your base ellipse centred at $(x_1,y_1)$ and the point of interest $(x_2,y_2)$.  Draw a line from $(x_1,y_1)$ through $(x_2,y_2)$, intersecting the ellipse at $(x,y)$.  Then $R$ is the distance between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, given by
$$R^2=(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2\ .$$
Also, $r$ is a factor say $\lambda$ times $R$.  To find $\lambda$ we have from the diagram
$$x-x_1=\lambda(x_2-x_1)\quad\hbox{and}\quad y-y_1=\lambda(y_2-y_1)\ .$$
Substituting into the equation of the ellipse
$$\frac{(x-x_1)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-y_1)^2}{b^2}=1$$
gives
$$\lambda^2\Bigl(\frac{(x_2-x_1)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y_2-y_1)^2}{b^2}\Bigr)=1\ .$$
From this you can find $\lambda$ (clearly positive) and then you have everything.